# angular caching in http request is not cached when using publishReplay and refCount rxjs operators

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, angular-httpclient

I'm looking for an example on http request cache in angular >=6, I tried an example as well but some how its not working.

Here is the sample code I tried but not working. [Stackblitz Code Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jggfzh?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Any help will be much appreciated.

@JBNizet, Thank you for looking into it. Here is the service code I have.

**What I'm trying to do :**

I wrote a sample code to test http cache request, I came to know that I can implement caching using publishReplay() and refCount() from rxjs.

**Expected Behavior :**

The service should make http get call only once.

**Actual Behavior :**

The service is making http get call every time I reload the browser.
If you observe the console.log statement in my service code, its printing every time undefined which I guess shouldn't.

**Component :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloService } from './hello.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  name = 'Angular';
  test$: Observable<String>;
  test: string = '';

  constructor(private helloService: HelloService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.helloService.test.subscribe(res => this.test = res);
  }

}
```

**Service :**

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { shareReplay, publishReplay, refCount, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/';

@Injectable()
export class HelloService {

  private test$: Observable<String>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get test(): Observable<String> {

   console.log('Object Testing : ', this.test$); \\ First time the value is undefined which is expected, second time when I execute also coming as undefined.

    if (!this.test$) {
      this.test$ = this.requestService().pipe(
        publishReplay(1),
        refCount()
      );
    }
    return this.test$;
  }

  private requestService(): Observable<String> {
    return this.http.get(API_ENDPOINT).pipe(
      map(response => response['type'])
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Define "not working", precisely. What are you doing, what do you  expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: @JBNizet, Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions. What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: I have updated my description, hope this explains your questions.

Comment: *The service is making http get call every time I reload the browser*: that's normal and expected: the cache is in the memory of your JavaScript application. When you refresh the browser, you restart from scratch: a new HTML page is loaded, and your application restarts. If you want something to be kept between browser refreshes, then you need to store it in a cookie, the session storage or the local storage. Not in memory.

Comment: I request you to refer this blog.. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2018/03/05/advanced-caching-with-rxjs.html . Also here is the final solution which was mentioned in the blog - https://advanced-caching-with-rxjs-step-4.stackblitz.io. This is the one I'm trying achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Understood your answer.